# One factor, two treatments, paired comparison: Wilcoxon or Sign test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, paired-comparisons

I have two dependent, paired samples. I am not sure if they have a normal distribution, therefore I am going for non-parametric hypothesis tests.

The only doubt remaining is if I should use Wilcoxon or Sign test. I have not find any answer to know what are the circumstances in which I should opt for one or another?

Second question is if I should transform the data using, for example, natural logarithm, or I can apply either Wilcoxon or Sign test with the data as it is?

Thanks a lot, any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: (1) Where you write "dependent," do you mean each $X$ value is *paired* with a $Y$ value? (2) What property are you trying to compare: the mean? The median? Something else?  (3) Have you noticed that each $Y$ value is (substantially) greater than each $X$ value at the same place in the list? In fact, it looks like the $Y$ values are at least ten times greater than the $X$ values, item by item. (4) Sixteen significant figures is unprecedented precision for data. It suggests these are not raw data but were computed somehow from other data. What was the computation?

Comment: Yes, each X is paired with a Y. I have just learnt few minutes ago a statistical test is not useful when having such evident differences. I wanted to compare means. The data is raw runtimes.

Comment: You are correct: sometimes the results are so glaringly obvious that any statistical test would be superfluous.  In such cases you might prefer making *estimates* rather than testing differences. There is a matter of what would be a good and appropriate way to estimate the difference in mean runtimes: should you average the ratios, for instance, or subtract the averages? That depends partly on what form of comparison is more meaningful to you, as well as on the statistical behavior of the data (such as exactly *how* these data got paired).